# How to convert object A to an array of objects with object A's properties and assign value and label to them

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, javascript-objects

I have an object:

```
{
 "id": 12432,
 "application": "pashmodin",
 "unit": null,
 "status": "gholam",
 "issueDate": "1999-06-24T00:00:00",
 "description": "hasan"
}
```

I want it to become an array like:

```
[
  {"label": "id", "value": 12432},
  {"label": "application", "value": "pashmodin"},
  {"label": "unit", "value": null},
  {"label": "status", "value": "gholam"},
  {"label": "issueDate", "value": "1999-06-24T00:00:00"},
  {"label": "description", "value": "hasan"}
]
```

where each object has a label and a value assigned to them. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const obj = {"id":12432,"application":"pashmodin","unit":null,"status":"gholam","issueDate":"1999-06-24T00:00:00","description":"hasan"}

const res = Object.entries(obj).map(([label, value]) => ({label, value}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj= {
 "id": 12432,
 "application": "pashmodin",
 "unit": null,
 "status": "gholam",
 "issueDate": "1999-06-24T00:00:00",
 "description": "hasan"
}

const arr =[];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key, i)=> arr.push({label: key, value: Object.values(obj)[i]}))

console.log(arr)
```